# Use of superagent ajax library in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to javascript build stack.
Sorry if my question title might seems similiar to other questions, but i haven't found one which answer my question.

Currently learning React + Redux and following this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/react-redux-ajax-middleware

Here's the code in question:

```
'use strict';

import superagentPromise from 'superagent-promise';
import _superagent from 'superagent';

const superagent = superagentPromise(_superagent, global.Promise);

const API_ROOT = 'https://conduit.productionready.io/api';

const responseBody = res => res.body;

const requests = {
  get: url =>
    superagent.get(`${API_ROOT}${url}`).then(responseBody)
};

const Articles = {
  all: page =>
    requests.get(`/articles?limit=10`)
};

export default {
  Articles
};
```

The actual questions:

1. Why use [`superagent-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-promise) ? Doesn't [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) stated this:

   > ES6 promises are supported. Instead of `.end()` you can call `.then()`
2. Where does this `global.Promise` come from ? I haven't write anything like `global.Promise = require('some-promise-library')` and AFAIK Node doesn't have default `global.Promise`. What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using this on the server.  Assuming you're not using a super old version of Node like 0.10 then it has Promise support.

The superagent-promise used to be required - it no longer is with the latest version of superagent.  Just use superagent by itself and use the built-in promise support.

If you need to use superagent on the client then any promise polyfill will work to support older browsers (e.g. babel-polyfill).

Comment: Yes i'm not using a super old version of Node (forgot the precise version, and i'm not on my dev machine now, sorry). So, `global.Promise` is actually Node's Promise support ? One more question, how actually do you recognize that i'm using this on server ? I'm a Node newbie

Comment: The use of 'global', which is not present in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you want to use the superagent with promise support, you need that superagent-promise wrapper module. that's all
2. Promise is natively supported by Node.js and it's globally accessible.
   Every global objects are available without loading them like process, setTimeout etc. you can just use Promise without global if you use the native Promise.

   Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(global,'Promise') This returns true

Comment: You don't need superagent-promise to have promise support for superagent if you are using ES6.

Comment: Superagent is a node module, so aren't you contradicting yourself when you say that you need an extra library to have promise support when using superagent?

Comment: Well... have a look at this npm [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-promise) it says promise wrapper for superagent. You must depend on superagent and your favorite Promise library directly. so What do you think?

Comment: Your answer says that you need superagent-promise to use superagent with promises. This is not true if you are using es6 which has promises built into the language specification.